# Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I cant get string result of my query....how can i solve it?

Model:

```
class Get_info extends CI_Model {

  function Get_info() {
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->database();

  }


  function getFirstName($email){
        $query_id=$this->db->query("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email='$email'");
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT firstname FROM `user_info` WHERE id='$query_id'");
        var_dump($query->row());
        return $query->result();

  }
}
```

Controller:

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$this->load->model('get_info'); 
$result = $this->get_info->getFirstName($email);
$profile = $result[0];

$newdata = array(
        'email' =>  $email,
        'firstname' => $profile
        );
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata( $newdata );
```

when i call var_dump($query) in modelit answer me like that: `object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#23 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(62) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(91) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["row_data"]=> NULL }`

when i call var_dump($profile ) in controller it answer me: `array(0) { }`

Where is my mistake? i am only want get string text from query and put it on data session..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query=$this->db->query("SELECT firstname FROM`user_info`WHERE id='$query_id'");`

here `$query_id` is the result of the previous query, not in *INT*.

You **should** be doing this, **protecting your queries** also:

```
$query_id = $this->db->query("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email=?", array($email))->row();

$query=$this->db->query("SELECT firstname FROM `user_info` WHERE id=?", array($query_id->user_id))->result();
```

You can also go for AR instead, and even maybe make a *unique query:*

```
return $this->db->select('user_info.firstname, user.email')
         ->from('user_info')
         ->join('user', 'user.user_id = user_info.id')
         ->where('user.email', $email)
         ->get()
         ->row();
```

Edited the query above and changed `result()` to `row()`, since you're looking for one record only. Now your other code must be changed also:

```
$result = $this->get_info->getFirstName($email);
$newdata = array(
             'email' =>  $result->email,
             'firstname' => $result->firstname
           );
```

Comment: it return me  another error:
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["firstname"]=> string(3) "awq" } } 
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in S:\home\test1.ru\www\application\models\Get_info.php on line 16